# Long to wide without temporary count column

Tags: python, pandas

Les's say my input is:

```
  doc_id  label
0      a  Apple
1      b   Book
2      c   Book
3      a   Book
4      b    Cat
5      a  Apple
6      c   Book
```

My data ^^

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"doc_id": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "c"],
                   "label": ["Apple", "Book", "Book", "Book", "Cat", "Apple", "Book"]
                    })
```

And my desired output is:

```
label   Apple  Book  Cat
doc_id
a         2.0   1.0  NaN
b         NaN   1.0  1.0
c         NaN   2.0  NaN
```

Which I can get with:

```
df["count"] = np.ones(len(df))

new_df = df.pivot_table(index="doc_id", columns="label", values="count", aggfunc="sum")
```

But creating an temporary column of counts that are all ones feels redundant, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I see, so all I had do is `df.pivot_table(index="doc_id", columns="label", aggfunc="sum")`, and not even worry about counts...certainly overthought this one.

Comment: And searching is challenging too sometimes because often you're thinking of it differently than how the tool to solve it is phrased.  However, what you have won't work.  Try `pd.crosstab(df.doc_id, df.label)`

Comment: ... Or any of the many other options that are laid out.  Some are faster than others.  Choose according to your performance needs.